# PHPUnit Stubbing Class methods declared as "final"

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing a unit test for a class method that calls another class's method using a mock, only the method that needs to be called is declared as final, so PHPUnit is unable to mock it. Is there a different approach I can take?

example:

class to be mocked

```
class Class_To_Mock
{
    final public function needsToBeCalled($options)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

my test case

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Class_To_Mock', array('needsToBeCalled'));
        $mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('needsToBeCalled')
             ->with($this->equalTo(array('option'));
    }
}
```

---

Edit: If using the solution provided by Mike B and you have a setter/getter for the object you're mocking that does type checking (to ensure the correct object was passed into the setter), you'll need to mock the getter on the class you're testing and have it return the other mock.

example:

class to be mocked

```
class Class_To_Mock
{
    final public function needsToBeCalled($options)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

mock

```
class Class_To_MockMock
{
    public function needsToBeCalled($options)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

class to be tested

```
class Class_To_Be_Tested
{
    public function setClassToMock(Class_To_Mock $classToMock)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function getClassToMock()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->getClassToMock()
             ->needsToBeCalled(array('option'));
    }
}
```

my test case

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $classToTest = $this->getMock('Class_To_Be_Tested', array('getClassToMock'));

        $mock = $this->getMock('Class_To_MockMock', array('needsToBeCalled'));

        $classToTest->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('getClassToMock')
                    ->will($this->returnValue($mock));

        $mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('needsToBeCalled')
             ->with($this->equalTo(array('option'));

        $classToTest->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think PHPUnit supports stubbing/mocking of final methods. You may have to create your own stub for this situation and do some extension trickery:

```
class myTestClassMock {
  public function needsToBeCalled() {
    $foo = new Class_To_Mock();
    $result = $foo->needsToBeCalled();
    return array('option');
  }
}
```

Found this in the PHPUnit Manual under [Chapter 11. Test Doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

> **Limitations**
>
> Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their original behavior.

Comment: There's an extra step you need if the class you're testing relies on a getter/setter that does type checking for the class/method being mocked. I added this to the original post.

Comment: @rr Please consider adding this as an answer, instead of putting the solution in a question.

Comment: @BartoszKP Theory is a beautiful thing. IMHO I provided a direct answer to the original question. If OP edited his question I'm not obligated to continue updating my answer to match the moving target that is this question. Also, this content is more than 3 years old an gets, on average, less than one hit per day. So the original question and answer most not be that interesting. Don't mock final methods.. don't introduce work-arounds for mocking final methods and your code will be much cleaner.

Comment: @MikeB Of course you're not obligated to do anything. I just suggested cleaning this whole thread up. I'm not a PHP expert so I didn't dive into details. If your answer is still valid as it is, then the solution part from OP's question should be moved to another answer.

Comment: @MikeB I agree with `Don't mock final methods.. don't introduce work-arounds for mocking final methods and your code will be much cleaner`, the problem is old legacy code that forces you to do it :'(

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled upon this issue today. Another alternative is to mock the interface that the class implements, given that it implements an interface and you use the interface as type hinting.

For example, given the problem in question, you can create an interface and use it as follows:

```
interface Interface_To_Mock
{
    function needsToBeCalled($options);
}

class Class_To_Mock implements Interface_To_Mock
{
    final public function needsToBeCalled($options)
    {
        ...
    }

}

class Class_To_Be_Tested
{
    public function setClassToMock(Interface_To_Mock $classToMock)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Interface_To_Mock', array('needsToBeCalled'));
        ...
    }
}
```